# Use java to download image from FTP

Tags: java

I got starting url, got a for( ) but don't now how to use webclient to download them, can someone help with it? and which "imports" are needed ?
I'm using-

```
System.in.WebClient client = new WebClient();  
byte [] bytedata = client.DownloadData(url);
client.DownloadFile(url,downloadPath);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a library to fetch files using FTP in java.

The most common is the commons one : http://commons.apache.org/net/